# Switch from Fabric to Firebase Crashlytics problem: The Crashlytics build ID is missing

Tags: android, firebase, build, google-fabric

After switch from Fabric to Firebase Crashlytics SDK I have a problem. Problem is as in the title: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.

I have json file generated from console(double checked these and keys with everything else looks ok). I have libs added in gradle. I'm calling 'throw new RuntimeException("Test Crash");' and getting an error with build ID which I have no idea what it is...

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I have answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63325427/firebase-crashlytics-java-lang-illegalstateexception-the-crashlytics-build-id/64679081#64679081 , may be this is the solution for your case

Comment: You can refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63795391/4601864

Answer (score 10):

Seems like instruction could have been missed out

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

Answer (score 6):

Be sure to have 2 things below:
In the **root build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.0'
    }
    ...
}
```

and under **app/build.gradle**:

```
...
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
...
```

Comment: This answer sums up exactly what is missing in the Firebase documentation. Should be the accepted one IMO.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using Fabric dependencies in your Firebase app. This error occurs when your Crashlytics Gradle plugin isn't correctly configured. I recommend going through [these onboarding instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started-new-sdk?platform=android#add-crashlytics) once more to make sure everything looks right in your integration.

Comment: I did it twice. What i have spotted now if add fabric url to maven, classpath and plugin but without implementation of library and without key in manifest - Crashlytics starting work without errors. Don't know what to do with this...

Comment: It very much sounds like you might be implementing both the Fabric and Firebase onboarding instructions. I'd consider writing into Firebase Support if you want help configuring your integration, since I wouldn't ask you to send me your gradle files and MainActivity over SO.

Comment: Ugh...it was missing apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' but still no mail with crash. It's not my day for work...

Comment: Your dashboard isn't receiving the crash, or you're just not receiving the email notification? If it's just the email, then I suggest clicking on the notifications setting in the Firebase console, in the top right, and making sure you have new issues set to on. Also, make sure you haven't received an email previously for that issue, since Firebase won't send duplicate emails for issues unless they exceed your Velocity Alerts threshold.