# Firebase Crashlytics - java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Crashlytics build ID is missing

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android, firebase-crash-reporting

As per new version of Firebase Crashlytics added in Our App and application stopped at launch time.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.

**App-Level Gradle**
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.1.1'

**Project-Levle Gradle**
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0'

Follow steps by step from Firebase guides
[Firebase Guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android&authuser=0)

But earlier Fabric version is too much better than current one.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Having the same issue. Will post solution here once I figure it out

Comment: This bug is annoying. We have it and I have done everything to help fixing it but no luck

Answer (score 78):

In the build.gradle at the application level, add the following imports
`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
`apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'`

Then, in the gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file, upgrade your gradle version to 5.6.4
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip`

I used to run my app with gradle 5.1.1 and upgrading to the version 5.6.4 fixed my problems

I hope it'll help you !

Comment: Thanks, this helped to resolve the issue. I've checked at https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ that 5.6.4 is the most recent version 5.

Comment: This is why google document sucks. There is no mention of this. Wasted 1 hr trying to add the id somehow by updating google-services.json and what not.

Comment: Also remember to include the buildscript dependencies classpath in the root build.gradle as mentioned by Amir Raza

Comment: I am trying to remove crashlytics since my team is migrating to Sentry. When i removed all references to Crashlytics i am getting this error
`E/FirebaseCrashlytics: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.`
how do i resolve this?

Answer (score 32):

That normally happens when the plugin `apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'` is missing in `build.gradle` app level.

Comment: no it's not. please don't make it an exact answer

Answer (score 24):

If anyone still have problem with this issue, try using crashlytics gradle verions `2.1.1` in project level gradle. I solved my problem by doing so.

```
buildscript {       
    ...
    dependencies {
        ... 
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.1'    
    }
}
```

Comment: While indeed downgrading this from 2.4.1 to 2.1.1 (or even 2.2.1) resolved the issue, it's probably a better option to update the cradle version in the gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file, as instructed by xerib: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63795391/2439941

Answer (score 23):

please add

```
 classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:x.x.x'
```

to your project's build gradle. And don't forget to add following lines to your app's build gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}
```

Answer (score 12):

It will also happen if you forgot to include
`classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'` in your project level `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Check that you have Google's Maven repository (if not, add it).
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        // ...

        // Check that you have the Google services Gradle plugin v4.3.2 or later
        // (if not, add it).
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'

        // Add the Crashlytics Gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Check that you have Google's Maven repository (if not, add it).
        google()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The only thing that solved my problem was to add the following line - `<string name="com.crashlytics.android.build_id">1</string>` to `strings.xml`, as suggested [here](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/642#issuecomment-1221520982).

Answer (score 4):

Add the code below to `project/android/app/build.gradle`

`apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'`

Answer (score 4):

In my case this error is caused by `shrinkResources = true` (in app/build.gradle) in combination with android-gradle-plugin version `8.3.0-alphaXX`.

In order to fix this I had to add a `keep.xml` file under `res/raw/keep.xml` with the following input:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@string/com.google.firebase.crashlytics.*" />
```

The actual reason why this bug was introduced by R8 and firebase can be found here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/5562#issuecomment-1825591774

Answer (score 1):

add this line

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid"
```

this will solve this problem

Comment: Don't see such a plugin listed @ https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries almost thought this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After several hours i finally figured it out. I used `./gradlew app:dependencies` command to list the dependency tree just to notice, that some libraries (that were not up to date) used older version of crashlytics library. I updated them and the issue was finally gone!

Answer (score 0):

I also struggle with this crash (just in my release builds) and as a temporary fix it helps me to turn off shrinking resources. TBH don't know the reason why it was causing this crash yet

So you can try to set `isShrinkResources = false` in your `app/build.gradle.kts` file if you have it enabled

Answer (score 0):

This solution from **google documentation**:

Gradle file **(project-level)**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
      // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
      google()  // Google's Maven repository
      mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }

    dependencies {
      ...

      // add this line
      classpath ("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle :2.9.9")
    }
}

allprojects {
  ...

  repositories {
    // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
    mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
  }
}
```

**module (app-level)** Gradle file

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")

    // Add the ID of the plugin
    id("com.google.firebase.crashlytics")
    ...
}
```